# How to open activities with multiple buttons in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, button, android-activity

I have an Activity with 3 buttons and I want each one of them to lead to others activities.
I code with KOTLIN !

XML code

```
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_1"
       android:layout_width="150dp"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
       android:background="@drawable/custom_buttons"
       android:text="Characters"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:textStyle="normal"
       app:flow_verticalAlign="top"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.31" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_2"
       android:layout_width="150dp"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:background="@drawable/custom_buttons"
       android:text="Matchs Up"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
       app:flow_verticalAlign="center"/>

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_3"
       android:layout_width="150dp"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:background="@drawable/custom_buttons"
       android:text="glossary"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />
```

MainActivity.KT

```
    val button: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_1)
    val button: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_2)
    val button: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_3)
    
    button.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this, Page1::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    button.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this, Page2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    button.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this, Page3::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

I have a red error on "val button : Button" -> Conflicting declarations: val button: Button, val button: Button.

What do I do wrong and is there a better way to do this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have 2 or more variables with the same name in the same scope.

`val button` **means:** "Create a NEW *(immutable)* variable called button". To solve the problem, assign a unique name to each variable. For example:

```kotlin
val button1: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_1)
val button2: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_2)
val button3: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_3)

button1.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(this, Page1::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
button2.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(this, Page2::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
button3.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(this, Page3::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

I assume that you are new to Kotlin. It's highly recommended to check out [**the official Kotlin docs**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html) and read the basic syntax or just [**Variables in Kotlin**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html#variables).

Comment: Wow thank you, like you said I'm new to Kotlin. I'll consult the Kotlin Docs next time, thanks again !